# bootstrap 4 modal doesn't open at first click using vue js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal

My bootstrap 4 modal doesn't show up when I press on my button, but my computed property is for triggered(from the console)

Here is my template code

```
<form>
    <!-- button that triggers the modal -->
    <div id="btnBereken">
      <a
        class="btn btn-success btn-lg"
        data-target="#exampleModal"
        v-on:click="Vali"
        v-bind:data-toggle="Validation"
      >Bereken</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!--modal itself-->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
  v-show="Ok"
></div>
```

Here is my script code I have one method and one computed property that is linked to `data-toggle` of my button

```
Vali: async function(){
  this.Ok =true;
}
```

and my computed property

```
Validation() {
  if (this.Ok) {
    console.log("getriggerd");
    return "modal";
  }
}
```

When I press on my button once it the pop doesn't trigger but the second time it does, and my value for `this.Ok` gets updated on my console and in VueJS dev tool

Comment: why are you using `Vali: async function()` ? i mean `async` keyword?

Comment: because i am fetching data from an api inside the method and i have to await for it, but i have put code inside a comment so i am sure it has no effect on the this.Ok and i also tried without async..

Comment: could you show how are you doing that API call?

Comment: I placed it in comment it. so it has nothing to do with it

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap and Vue together, which means that they're going to fight over control of the DOM. Isn't your data-toggle value supposed to be "modal"?

Comment: Yes it is, i inspect the button element and when i click on it it adds data-toggle="modal" attribute to it, but then it won't show the modal itself. when i click again on it then it shows the modal. i think the data-toggle should be in place before i call the Vali() method, but that's not what i actually want bcs i have to validate stuff inside the vali...to decide this.Ok will be true or false

Comment: You aren't going to get Bootstrap to work with Vue like that. Bootstrap doesn't expect data-toggle to change. You might want to try [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/), or making a [wrapper component](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) to segregate the Bootstrap-controlled pieces of DOM from the Vue-controlled ones.

Comment: Thanks boostrap-vue did the job.